# Wrap __init__ of external class to ignore surplus arguments

Tags: python

I have a third-party class that takes a number of arguments in its `__init__` method.

```py
class ThirdPartyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        pass
```

I want to be able to instantiate the class given surplus parameters in a dictionary (as below), which throws an error due to the parameters `d` and `e`.

```py
params = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3, "d": 4, "e": 5}
ThirdPartyClass(**params)
```

How can I write a convenient wrapper that works similar to adding `**kwargs` to the `__init__` of `ThirdPartyClass` without modifying the source code of `ThirdPartyClass` in any way?

Of course I could write my own mock class of `ThirdPartyClass`, but would prefer a better solution.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I don't want to hard code the argument names. Still, I probably could use `inspect` to do the job. Also, the solution should be general and work for any external third-party class.

Comment: What should happen to the surplus parameters? Should they just be thrown away?

Comment: Is it assumed you know the paramters?

Comment: If you don't know the params, you'll need to get clever with something like `inspect`

Comment: Did you try writing a function that accepts `**kwargs` and uses the values in `kwargs` to call `ThirdPartyClass`? Does the wrapper need to work for more classes than this? Do you know the actual parameter names? I don't understand what the actual difficulty is.

Comment: The wrapper should work for more classes and be a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a fully general solution, probably the most elegant approach is to write a decorator. This will work with both functions and classes, as they are both callable (you call the class when you instantiate it). You can apply the decorator with `@` syntax to your own code, or use it as a higher-order function to wrap library code.

In order to be able to handle an arbitrary function signature, we will use the `inspect` module in order to figure out the parameter names. There are two caveats:

- If the function has a parameter to accept variable keyword arguments (`**kwargs`, or another name) already, then we don't need to change anything, and indeed *should not* change anything.
- Otherwise, if the function has a parameter to accept variable positional arguments (`*args`, or another name), then its name is not usable in the arguments for the call, and should be excluded when we filter incoming keyword arguments.

Thus:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature, Parameter

def ignore_extra_keywords(func):
    params = signature(func).parameters.values()
    if any(p.kind == Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD for p in params):
        return func
    names = {p.name for p in params if p.kind != Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL}
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # using `names` as a closure
        return func(*args, **{k: kwargs[k] for k in (kwargs.keys() & names)})
    return wrapper
```

Now we can do

```
ignore_extra_keywords(ThirdPartyClass)(**params)
```

or

```
@ignore_extra_keywords
def my_func(a, b, c):
    print(f'I got: {a}, {b}, {c}')

my_func(1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
```

Comment: I think you want to expand/deref (ie: `**{k: kwargs[k] ... }`) the `{k: kwargs[k] ... }` in the `func()` call on the 2nd last line there?

Comment: Yep, fixed (and updated the example to something that would have failed before and now works properly). Of course I would manage to typo the crucial part, and also write overly simple tests that would miss the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you filter the dict like this, knowing that "a", "b", and "c" are good params?

```
class ThirdPartyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        pass

bad_params = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3, "d": 4, "e": 5}
good_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
good_params = {}
for k,v in bad_params.items():
    if k in good_keys:
        good_params[k] = v

ThirdPartyClass(**good_params)
```

Oneliner dict comp alternative:

```
good_params = {k:v for (k,v) in bad_params.items() if k in good_keys}
```

Comment: That loop is a good candidate for a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: just did that! @Barmar

Comment: I could use the `inspect` module to find the parameter names of `__init__`, right? So it should definitely work!

Comment: @stn53 yes you def. could

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* the paramters, you can just write something like:

```
{k:params[k] for k in (params.keys() & {'a','b','c'})}
```

Which returns

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

In this case.

So, the code can be something to the effect of:

```
obj = ThirdPartyClass(**{k:params[k] for k in (params.keys() & {'a','b','c'})})
```

If you don't know the correct parameters, you can get them using:

```
import inspect
correct_parameters = set(inspect.signature(ThirdPartyClass).parameters)
```

So it becomes something like:

```
obj = ThirdPartyClass(**{k:params[k] for k in (params.keys() & correct_paramters)})
```

Comment: But in that case, why filter the dict at all? Why not just `obj = ThirdPartyClass(a=params['a'], b=params['b'], c=params['c'])`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel good point

Comment: The `inspect` approach is going to run into issues if the signature include `*args` or `**kwargs`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, but then it's going to be ambiguous anyway.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Please see my answer.